# Change CSS3 Animation keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I’m trying to change CSS Animation keyframes, it’s bouncing *Y axis* direction, but I’m trying to change it to *X axis* means trying to bounce left to right or right to left.

*Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/5y8ebfcw/

**HTML:**

```
<div class='thisone'></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.thisone {
-webkit-animation-name: slybounce;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-moz-animation-name: slybounce;
-moz-animation-duration: 3s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-delay: 0;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slybounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -5);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -5);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slybounce {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -5);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 5px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -5);
  }
}
```

I have tried this by changing `translate(0, 5px);` to `translateX(0, 5px);`
*Problem Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/5y8ebfcw/5/ 

But it’s not working. *So my question is how to Animation bounce left to right or right to left.*

Thanks.

Comment: can't you use `.animate()` method and animate it through `margin-left` property ? Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3SYka/2/) fiddle will give you some idea

Comment: I guess you have got your answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invert the operands in translate(x,y), from `translate(0,-5)` / `translate(0,+5)` to `translate(-5,0)` / `translate(+5,0)`.

[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/5y8ebfcw/1/)

Or even better, use [translateX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#translateX) instead of translate